# App crashes when using NSStringFromClass() in release target

Tags: ios, swift

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently facing a strange issue with some **Swift 3** code.

I have a custom logging class (using **XCGLogger**) :

```swift
struct Log {
    #if DEBUG
        fileprivate static let Logger: XCGLogger = {
            let logger = XCGLogger(identifier: "API")

            if let standardConsoleDestination = logger.destination(withIdentifier: XCGLogger.Constants.baseConsoleDestinationIdentifier) as? ConsoleDestination {
                standardConsoleDestination.showLogIdentifier = true
                standardConsoleDestination.showFunctionName = false
                standardConsoleDestination.showThreadName = false
                standardConsoleDestination.showLevel = true
                standardConsoleDestination.showFileName = false
                standardConsoleDestination.showLineNumber = false
                standardConsoleDestination.showDate = true
                standardConsoleDestination.outputLevel = .debug
            }

            return logger
        }()
    #endif

    fileprivate static func log(_ level: XCGLogger.Level, message: String) {
        #if DEBUG
            Logger.logln("[] \(message)", level: level, userInfo: [:])
        #endif
    }

    static func warning(_ message: String) {
        log(.warning, message: message)
    }

    static func parseFailure(in aClass: AnyClass, json: [String: Any]) {
        let className = NSStringFromClass(aClass)
        Log.warning("Failed to create \(className) object from JSON: \(json)")
    }
}
```

The **DEBUG** pre-processor directive is activated for Debug mode.

Then I'm using this method to instantiate an object from a JSON payload :

```swift
required init?(json: [String: Any]) {
    guard
        let value1 = json["value1"] as? String,
        let value2 = json["value2"] as? String
        else {
            Log.parseFailure(in: type(of: self), json: json)
            return nil
    }

    self.value1 = value1
    self.value2 = value2
}
```

This is pretty basic but it's just to illustrate the case I've encountered.

I'm getting the following crash :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000e115ebec8

1   MyProject                   0x00000001015cb92c static Log.parseFailure -> () (in MyProject) (Log.swift:0)
2   MyProject                   0x000000010151c9a0 Object.init(json : [String : Any]) -> Object? (Object.swift:0)
...
```

I'm sure it's something dumb... Maybe the class being deallocated before the Log happens, resulting in the **self** typeof to be nil.

Any insight is welcome on the topic so thanks for your contribution / comment.

**EDIT**

I've been able to replicate the issue by enabling testing on release mode, it seems that disabling optimisation to check the content of the parameters solved the issue.

Maybe one of these is adding some sort of security... I'll dig deeper while trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Can you provide crash report?

Comment: Is there even a remote possibility that the `json` itself was `nil`? Maybe when your backend encountered a problem and returned empty response?

Comment: @Losiowaty Nope, the backend's payload was always supplied. This crash happened only when one of the key was missing (which should have never happened in the first place...).

Comment: Does `self` == nil because its a failable init method?  There is no `self` yet.

Comment: @dmorrow that's what I'm wondering, the `Log` class is expecting the type of the class but the `self` might in fact be `nil` since we can't instantiate the class due to the missing field.

Comment: A quick playground test disproves this.

Comment: @dmorrow yup, I did that, with no success

Comment: It's probably that you're returning `nil` on an initializer? Initializers are supposed to always return non-nil values since you're allocating memory space.

Comment: @AlejandroIván so relying on `Object` class instead of `self` should be better, I'll give it a try since I'm now able to reproduce quickly the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the culprit :

```swift
let className = NSStringFromClass(aClass)
Log.warning("Failed to create \(className) object from JSON: \(json)")
```

The `NSStringFromClass()` function is breaking when **Swift** optimization is enabled (*SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL*).

I replaced it with the following :

```swift
let className = String(describing: aClass)
Log.warning("Failed to create \(className) object from JSON: \(json)")
```

And now everything is working but it was a pain to test...

I'll update the post name to reflect that this bug is different than an issue with a dictionary.